# How to loop through the attributes of a JSON obj?

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to loop on a JSON object?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3022358/how-to-loop-on-a-json-object)

I'm trying to find out how to loop through the attributes of a JSON obj. I can get the attributes by specifying the key (see below), but how do I just loop through all of them?

```
var jsonStr = '{"Items":[{"Title": "Title 1", "Description":"Description 1"}]}';

var json_parsed = $.parseJSON(jsonStr);


// Cycle through all list items
$.each(json_parsed.Items, function(i, val) {
    var listItem = $(this);

    var title = listItem.attr('Title');
    var description = listItem.attr('Description');

    // Instead, loop through all attributes

}
```

Comment: Note that there is nothing called a "JSON object". When you parse some JSON string, you get a javascript object.

Comment: Please, don't use jQuery like this!

Answer (score 25):

```
for (var name in json_parsed) {
    console.log(name + "=" + json_parsed[name]);
}
```

If you need to check if the corresponding property is defined on the object in question, not on some of those on the prototype chain (this is ridiculous for the case in question, but still useful), you can add this check:

```
if (json_parsed.hasOwnProperty(name))
    console.log(name + "=" + json_parsed[name]);
```

**EDIT**

To actually iterate all array objects' attributes, use this snippet:

```
var items = json_parsed.Items;
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
    console.log("Item #" + i);
    for (var name in items[i]) {
        console.log(name + "=" + items[i][name]);
    }
}
```

Comment: Careful, this can iterate over more than just the own properties of the object.

Comment: @Kiyura only if the object is an array

Comment: @Kiyura if the object is the result of some parsing from JSON, there is no problem.

Comment: It can, though the case in question can hardly be affected by this. Will fix to account for this, though.

Comment: Yes, for JSON objects it's no problem, but if someone learns they can use for..in like this, they might go and use it on a normal JS object later on and be surprised that it's pulling in prototype properties.

Comment: @Kiyura: The JSON is parsed into normal JS objects. It's only an issue if you've added enumerables to `Object.prototype`, and if that's the case, you have bigger problems.

Comment: Alexander, thanks for your message. When I use the for loop on the json_parsed, I get Items=[object Object]. However, I would like to iterate over the attributes of the listItem variable... Can you help?

Comment: This was just an example of what you might do. If you need to iterate all objects in the `Items` array, see the edit.

Answer (score 2):

A JSON object is just a Javascript object. If you're already using jQuery, you can use $.each() again on it to iterate over its named properties.

Answer (score 1):

```
var jsonStr = '{"Items":[{"Title": "Title 1", "Description":"Description 1"}]}';

var json_parsed = JSON.parse(jsonStr);

var items = json_parsed.Items; // an array

for (var i=0; i<items.length; i++) { // loop over it

     var listItem = items[i]; // an object

     for (var prop in listItem) { // enumerate its property names

         // prop is "Title", "Description" etc
         listItem[prop] // is the respective value

     }

}
```

Comment: Bergi, thanks for your message. This code gives me: Object
Title: "Title1"
Description: "Description1" ... and then a whole list of functions.

Comment: Uh, what? Which functions? Did you do harm to `Object.prototype`?

Comment: for example function (a,b){return new e.fn.init(a,b,h)}. This is the code to print out the properties:      for (var prop in listItem) { // enumerate its property names
  // prop is "Title", "Description" etc
  console.log(listItem[prop]) // is the respective value

     }

Comment: Didn't I told you not to (ab)use jQuery? :) If you really want to use that `.each` wrapper, `var listItem = this;` or `var listItem = val;`